# Are there any official standards for TLS version strings?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

Here for instance they mention a couple:

> e.g. TLSv1 or TLSv1.2 etc.

https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/apache/tomcat/HEAD/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLSupport.java?line=58

Is there an official definition for the possible values of TLS version?  Does it vary from library to library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list for Java is provided in [Standard Algorithm Names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html), under 'SSLContext algorithms'. I think there is a general consensus but no formal specification.